# Fresh Laravel 9 installation with vue 3 scaffold and vite not redering component

Tags: vue.js, vite, laravel-9

I did a fresh laravel 9.19 installation with vue scaffolding and vite.js. everything works well just that the vue example component that comes with the fresh install of laravel refused to be rendered on the browser.

my environment

- chrome Version - 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- node version - 19.3
- Laravel 9.19

basically, as of today i'm using the latest version of everything.
I get a blank white screen on my browser with no errors on the console but the vue component is not rendering

I have tried suggestions from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/vite-with-laravel-and-vue-3-show-blank-screen) which is similar to my issue but nothing worked

content of my files

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                // 'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

resouces/js/app.js file

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
 
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance. You may then begin
 * registering components with the application instance so they are ready
 * to use in your application's views. An example is included for you.
 */

const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
//     app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), definition.default);
// });

/**
 * Finally, we will attach the application instance to a HTML element with
 * an "id" attribute of "app". This element is included with the "auth"
 * scaffolding. Otherwise, you will need to add an element yourself.
 */

app.mount('#app');
```

resouces/views/layouts/app.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
      {{--  vue component goes here --}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i changed the boilerplate code in my `resouces/js/app.js` file and it worked. i don't know why.

i changed this

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const app = createApp({});
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
app.mount('#app');
```

to this

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

createApp(ExampleComponent).mount('#app');
```

Comment: It worked because createApp takes a root component as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

So I recently just encountered this issue. I got a blank page when I run `npm run dev`. Thankfully on the console, I got the error message in the image below.

[image]

So I went ahead to my app.js to change my Vue import from

`import { createApp } from "vue";`

to

`import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'`;

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same trouble with Laravel 10 and Vue 3 with Vite and Bootstrap with Laravel Fortify. I am now creating a scaffold for the same. Please check it out and contribute too if you have any suggestions. https://github.com/the-provost/fusionboost-kit